# Hot reloading in visual studio 2017 for asp.net core spa (react) app with custom web server used via proxy

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, single-page-application, reactjs.net, hot-reload

I have a asp.net core 2.2 [react template based app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

The react app under ClientApp has my own build script for react app which compiles stuff in a lib folder under ClientApp via 'npm run build' custom script.

More importantly, the app runs with a custom node/express based web server (npm run start in clientapp would launch a web server script which would listen on say port 6000)

I cannot use the standard react development server that comes with template. 
The startup.cs file of asp.net core layer uses it via spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer (http://localhost:6000)

```
app.UseSpa (spa =>
             {
                 spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                 if (env.IsDevelopment ())
                     {
                     string reactDevServerUri = Configuration["ReactDevServerUri"];
                     spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer(reactDevServerUri);
                     }
             });
```

During debug session in vs 2017, on any change in typescript files in ClientApp\src folder, i need to
1.Invoke script 'build' in ClientApp\package.json to compile react app in ClientApp\lib folder
2. Restart my web server running via script 'start' to pick new changes in lib
3.Reload browser

Currently i have added a 'debug' script which uses nodemon to track changes in react app and restart server after build script

```
    "debug": "nodemon -e ts,tsx --watch src --exec \"npm run build && npm run start\""
```

I still have to reload browser myself and it keeps failing until build/start are finished. I need a better way to do this in one go by proper configuration of encapsulating asp.net core project.

Please help me figure out a way :)